# Lumia 925 shows charging icon even when it's not charging

Tags: battery, lumia-925

Since upgrading my Nokia Lumia 925 to Windows Phone 8.1, I'm seeing a strange behaviour: the battery sign shows that it's charging even after I unplug it from the power cord. Sometimes, after a reboot this symbol goes away but comes back randomly. It actually does not charge the battery but just displays this symbol (in the background, battery gets discharged with usage). I have never used a wireless charger and have no idea why this is happening.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would recommend doing a hard reset. This usually fixes most of the update-related problems.

Comment: Regarding your WiFi issue, please [post a new question](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (but be sure to [search](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/search?q=) first to see if it's been asked already).

Comment: I did multiple hard resets but the issue keeps coming back. Please suggest